# how to show month view horizontally in rad calender?

Tags: asp.net, telerik

How to show rad calender month view horizontally.
here is my code:

```
<telerik:RadCalendar ID="rcJan" runat="server" SingleViewColumns="31"
    SingleViewRows="1" FocusedDate="2012-01-01" ShowOtherMonthsDays="false">
</telerik:RadCalendar>
```

but its showing only 24 days from January month.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by only some settings as followos

Simply specify the orientation of the calendar by setting the Orientation property to either **RenderInColumns** or **RenderInRows**.

EDITED::

**get_orientation === Returns 1 if the orientation is "RenderInRows", 2 if it is "RenderInColumns".**

OR

**radCalendar.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i also added Orientation="RenderInRows" but its not giving the desired output

Comment: have you use exact key word for orientation?

Comment: ya i have exact Orientation="RenderInRows".

Comment: check radCalendar.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal; this might help you

Comment: RadCalendar1.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal; this line of code has thrown a error.